# Quickly converting Word Doc into HTML

Tags: html, text, converters

I am trying to convert a word document into html. I used an online converter http://word2cleanhtml.com/ but it does not keep the pictures I have in my file. From the html I will be making a nook and kindle ebook. Does anyone have a tool or suggestion for this project?

Using `save as html` in word doesn't keep images either.

Comment: In word. Save as... HTML
Maybe even better, save as PDF.

Comment: That gives me 16,000 lines of code, and doesn't keep the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the KindlePreviewer: http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html/?docId=1000765261

Then, save your file as HTML. Images will not be part of the html file, instead they are stored in a separate folder. 
Open the resulting html file into the KindlePreviewer, it will find the images in the images folder and add them to your book.